# How to increase download size in Livelink

Tags: opentext, livelink

I'm using Livelink to download files through Enterprise Connect.

When I download files to desktop, after downloading some files, it shows me an error message that I have exceeded download limit set by the administrator.

My question: is there any way to increase/change  the download limit in Livelink? I'm using an user which has admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

That's a server parameter. You have to change the parameter in IIS (assuming you use IIS?).

Answer (score 0):

As Steffen already mentioned, that is a server parameter. But OT LiveLink is usually running on a Tomcat server.

Take a look on the config file "**webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml**", within the Tomcat server installation folder.

There is a part "multipart-config"

```
<multipart-config>
  <!-- 50MB max -->
  <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
  <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

100 MB => 104857600, 200 MB => 209715200